# Maximum value of trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

If 
$r=3+\tan c \tan a, \quad  
 q=5+\tan b \tan c, \quad
 p=7+\tan a \tan b$

Provided $a,b,c$ are positive and 
$a+b+c=\dfrac{\pi}2$

Find the maximum value of 
$\sqrt p + \sqrt q + \sqrt r$ .

Comment: What are your thoughts so far on this?

Comment: Immediately we have $\sum\tan A\tan B=1$

Answer (score 4):

Let $x = \tan a \tan b, \; y = \tan b \tan c, \; z = \tan c \tan a$, then $x, y, z > 0$ and $x+y+z=1$.

We need to now maximize $\sqrt{3+x}+\sqrt{5+y}+\sqrt{7+z}$.  As $\sqrt t$ is concave, using Karamata's inequality and $(3+x, 5+y, 7+z) \succ (3+x+y+z, 5, 7) = (4, 5, 7)$, we have $\sqrt{3+x}+\sqrt{5+y}+\sqrt{7+z} \le 2+\sqrt5 + \sqrt7$.

Equality is never achieved, but one can get as close to the value when $b \ll   a \to 0^+, c \to \frac{\pi}2^-$, so we do not have a maximum but a supremum.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my comment to lab ? I have the same question for you.

Comment: Thanks ! I prefer this one. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sqrt p=P$ etc.

$$R^2-3+Q^2-5+P^2-7=1\iff P^2+Q^2+R^2=16$$

Let $P=4\cos A,Q=4\sin A\cos B,R=4\sin A\sin B$

$P+Q+R=4[\cos A+\sin A(\cos B+\sin B)]\le4[\cos A+\sqrt2\sin A]$ if $\sin A\ge0$

Now $\cos A+\sqrt2\sin A=\sqrt3\cos\left(A-\arccos\dfrac1{\sqrt3}\right)\le\sqrt3$

Comment: May I confess that I do not understand the result ? If I set  $a=b=\epsilon$, $c=\frac \pi 2-2\epsilon$, $F=\sqrt p + \sqrt q + \sqrt r$ seems to go to  $\sqrt{\frac{7}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{11}{2}}+\sqrt{7}\approx 6.86179$ and $F$ is concave down. Where is my mistake ? Thaks for helping the old man to understand.

Comment: I saw a short comment ... which disappeared immediately !! Any problem ?

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: The function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is concave.